# How to convert the tuple elements to string, without losing the tuple properties?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I created a tuple by reading data from a MySQL table. All the elements are of mixed data types and to be able to apply few string operations (upper case, removal of special characters etc), I need to convert all those elements to string.

I tried "".str() and .join() but the resultant is a pure string and I lose information about individual elements.

Something like:

```
(ABC, XYZ, 234, QWE, 578)   <-- mixed datatypes but I can do tuple[0] to just fetch ABC
```

The cursor returns multiple records. The struct_address_str[0] returns the first record (like the example above). The struct_address_str[0][0] returns the first element of the row. After I make the first transformation, the struct_address_str[0][0] no more returns the first element but first character of the element.

However, after the transformation, if I do tuple[0][0], I get back A while I want to the output to be ABC.

How do I get this working?

Following is the code that I am using:

```
    cursor = conn.cursor();

    ### Structure Address Data ###
    cursor.execute("SELECT id,... FROM ...");

    #converted the cursor to list
    struct_address = list(cursor.fetchall())     


    #converted all the list elements to string
    struct_address_str = [str(i) for i in struct_address] 

    #Checking the values                          
    print(struct_address_str[0][1], sep="\n")
    print(struct_address_str[0][2], sep="\n")
    print(struct_address_str[0], sep="\n")

    #converted all the list elements to uppercase
    struct_address_upper = [i.upper() for i in struct_address_str] 

    #removing all the special characters
    #cli_add_no_sp_char = [s.translate(str.maketrans('', '', '\'(#),-\".')) for s in cli_address_upper]
    struct_add_no_sp_char = [s.translate(str.maketrans('\'(#),-\"./', '         ', '')) for s in struct_address_upper]
```

Comment: The line `struct_address_str = [str(i) for i in struct_address]` seems to be doing exactly what you say you want to do.  What exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: Like I mentioned above, I intend to get ABC as output of print(struct_address_str[0][1]), instead of A.

Comment: That's a completely unreasonable intention.  `struct_address_str[0]` is the entire first element of the list, if that's a string then adding `[1]` can only be a single character from that string.

Comment: The cursor returns multiple records. The struct_address_str[0] returns the first record (like the example above). The struct_address_str[0][0] returns the first element of the row. After I make the first transformation, the struct_address_str[0][0] no more returns the first element but first character of the element.

And looks like you downvoted without even understanding the question. Thanks. I take that as my fault too since I probably didn't elaborate well enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about :

```
struct_address_str = [[str(i) for i in x] for x in struct_address]
```

And then again:

```
struct_address_upper = [[i.upper() for i in x] for x in struct_address_str]
```

Of course you could combine the two in one line by using "str(i).upper()". I would probably define a function sanitize(i) making all needed operations and then use it in the list comprehension.

Comment: Thanks @Rolvernew that game me an idea. I was able to use that construct.